# Limit in combination with an infinite series

Tags: limits, fourier-series, riemann-zeta, bernoulli-numbers

How would I go about showing the following limits that involve infinite series

$$ \lim_{x \to 0^{+}} \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{n^{2k+1}} \sin (2\pi n(x - \frac{1}{2})) = 0 \text{ with } k \in \mathbb{N} $$

and

$$ \lim_{x \to 0^{+}} \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{n^{2k}} \cos (2\pi n(x - \frac{1}{2})) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{n^{2k}} \cos (-\pi n) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^{2k}} \text{ with } k \in \mathbb{N} $$

I first had the idea that perhaps the rule of "the limit of the sums is the sum of the limits" would extend to the realm of infinite convergent series, but I came up with a counter example

$$ \lim_{x \to 0^{+}} \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{n} \sin (2\pi n(x - \frac{1}{2})) = \frac{\pi}{2} \neq 0 $$

I think I can prove the first limit by using Bernoulli polynomials, but that is not the kind of proof I'm looking for (I want to prove something about Bernoulli numbers by using this limit, so it would be kind of invalid to do so).

Idem so for limit no. 2, by using Euler's expression for even values of the Riemann zeta function, but again I want to prove something the other way around.

Any ideas? I must add that I'm an undergraduate math student, so my knowledge is very limited :-)

Answer (score 2):

The funny thing is that the counter example you gave (k=0) was the ONLY valid one. Let us see why :

First, set $k > 0$. Then,
$$
 \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{n^{2k+1}} \sin (2\pi n(x - \frac{1}{2})) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^{2k+1}} \sin (2\pi nx)
$$

Then, $ | \frac{1}{n^{2k+1}} \sin (2\pi nx) | \leq \frac{1}{n^{2k+1}} $ and $\sum \frac{1}{n^{2k+1}}$ converges. This means that your sum converges absolutly, hence you can exchange the limit and sum operations.

If $k=0$ on the other hand, the series does not absolutely converge and the values of the sum of the limits and the limit of the sums can be (and is) different.

Cheers,

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! I agree with you that for $k = 0$ the series is not absolutely convergent while it is for $k \geq 1$. I just did not know that when a series is absolutely convergent (for any $x$, I assume this condition must be added too) you can swap the sum and the limit. That makes life very easy! Could you refer me to a proof of that statement?

Comment: @Jori : Of course, it is necessary to have the majoration for any $x$. Here you even have something stronger : the sum (seen as a sum of fonctions) is normally convergent ( see [Normal convergence on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_convergence)). This entails uniform absolute convergence, which is extremely powerful (and allows you to prove the exchange of limits, continuity and even C-1 derivabiity for $k > 1$).

Answer (score 1):

For $k=1,2,3,...$, you have
$$
\begin{align}
0\leq\left|\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{n^{2k+1}} \sin (2\pi n(x - \frac{1}{2}))\right| &\leq \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^{2k+1}}=\zeta(2k+1)<\infty\\\\
0\leq\left|\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{n^{2k}} \cos (2\pi n(x - \frac{1}{2}))\right| &\leq \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^{2k}}=\zeta(2k)<\infty
\end{align}
$$ thus, by uniform convergence on $[0,1]$, it is allowed to interchange the 'limit' and the 'infinite sum', then conclude with
$$
\begin{align}
 \sin (2\pi n(x - \frac{1}{2})) \to 0 & \,\, \text{as}\,\, x \to 0^+,\\\\
(-1)^n\cos (2\pi n(x - \frac{1}{2})) \to 1 & \,\, \text{as}\,\, x \to 0^+.
\end{align}
$$